# How do I close an explorer window using java? I am able to use Runtime class to open it

Tags: java

```
try{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
    p.destroy();
}catch(Exception e){
   //Handle Exception
}
```

So, the above code can be used to open up an explorer window or any other folder as needed, but how do I close the opened window?
I thought of using the Robot class, but not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the process from with in your Java application (ex. by calling Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder.start()) then you have a valid Process reference to it. In your case p

```
Process p = rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");
```

you can invoke the `destroy()` method in Process class to kill that particular process.

But note it will kill the entire process which will include closing your explorer window.

Comment: Did not see that. If he has done that then does he want the individual window frame to be close? If yes that cannot be done by java.

Comment: This way all my other windows get closed too, right?
I tried this the first time around. Which was the problem.
I need to close that particular window which was just opened.
It's fine for apps like iTunes or whatever, cuz only one of them is open, but not for a folder or something.